# Keep leading zeros with colsplit in R

Tags: r

I'm using colsplit to split a large string to columns.
there are numbers in the string with leading zeros.
How can I prevent colsplit from converting them to numeric values?

Example:
value in string: 0000122517
after colsplit this becomes: 122517

I need the leading zeros, and the values can be of any length, so I
cannot add the zeros afterwards.

Kind regards,
Oene Douma

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: str <- "Client~0000122517"  
colsplit(str, split = "~", names = " ")  

Returns:  
      X.    NA.  
1 Client 122517  

this should be:  
      X.    NA.  
1 Client 0000122517

Comment: Try with `read.table` i.e. `read.table(text=str, sep="~", header=FALSE, colClasses = c("character", "character"))`

Comment: You are a hero,  Thank you, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table`

```
read.table(text=str, sep="~", header=FALSE, colClasses = c("character", "character"))
```